# Scientific Programming on Mac using Objective-C/Cocoa for MATLAB Users

Tags: software, matlab

I want to get started on scientific programming on the Mac using Objective-C.  I am very familiar with MATLAB which makes it easy to store complex-valued waveform data in vectors and generating plots.  I was wondering if there might be a good resource that might compare how you would implement common MATLAB operations (i.e. creating an array of complex values or generating a mesh plot) in an Objective-C/Cocoa environment.

Comment: You might want to take a look at interfacing with the Visualization ToolKit (VTK). http://macresearch.org/cocoa_for_scientists_part_xiv_beginning_3d_visualization.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to resign from the huge, powerful stack of cross-platform tools for a sake of using an esoteric language built exclusively for making GUIs and working only on a hardware that can't be reasonably used for any serious HPC?

Comment: @mbq Maybe to integrate well with an existing xGrid setup?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of any Objective-C-specific libraries or frameworks, but there are a large number of libraries written in and available for plain C, and you should be able to use them with Objective-C.

Using C allows you to use [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/), [gsl](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/), [LAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK), and loads of other useful numerical libraries. I would advise against trying to code the matlab routines yourself. Internally, matlab likely uses well-known numerical libraries itself.

If you're looking for numerical libraries in an object-oriented language, you might want to look into using C++, which has [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) and [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/) available.

Answer (score 5):

if you are completely unfamiliar with C, but are using matlab as your base starting point, i would actually recommend fortran90 over C. the languages are so incredibly similar it is scary (as far as syntax goes at least)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at this series of articles on scientific computing with Cocoa from [MacResearch](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa_for_scientists).